# VSTS - Add a field to a task definition, with a value based on another field

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions, azure-devops-rest-api

I'd like to add the following functionality to my VSTS extension (plugin).
I have a build task definition which includes a string input. I need to create a new version of my plugin, which adds a new string input to this task.

The new input should be created with a value, which is based on the value of the old field.

For example, if the old field has a value of **a/b/c.txt**, then the value of the new field should be **{ path="a/b/c.txt" }**.

Is there a way to use node.js or Powershell to achieve this? Another way perhaps?

Comment: Do you mean - in your custom task definition you have string input, and you want to add another field (on the same task definition) with the value that based on the first string input field?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. I'd like the new filed to be on the same task definition.

Comment: So you can catch the first string input value, manipulate it (add {path=}, for example) and put the value on the second field. the issue is how to manipulate?

Comment: Yes. correct. I'm looking for a way to set a value to a field automatically, based on the value of the other field.

Comment: Do you mean Work Item Type - Task or Build Task?

Answer (score 0):

From my test, it's not able to get the value of a filed from another one. You may try to get the field when the task runs and set value to another field.